# Show $S_n$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to direct product of $S_{n_1}, ..., S_{n_k}$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

Let $n=n_1+n_2+...+n_k$ be a partition of the positive integer $n$ , then how do I show that the symmetric group $S_n$ contains a subgroup which is isomorphic to direct product of $S_{n_1},S_{n_2} , ..., S_{n_k}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Split the elements into disjoint sets such that their cardinalities match the partition. Now,
consider the set of those  permutations that permutes only elements in the same set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the subgroup generated by the following $k$ disjoint $n_i$ cycles:

$$\Big(1\cdots n_1\Big),\;\Big((n_1+1)\cdots (n_1+n_2)\Big),\;\cdots\;,\;\Big((n_1+\cdots+n_{k-1}+1)\cdots (n_1+\cdots+n_k)\Big)$$
Together with:

$$\Big(12\Big),\;\Big((n_1+1)(n_1+2)\Big),\;\cdots\;,\;\Big((n_1+\cdots+n_{k-1}+1)(n_1+\cdots+n_{k-1}+2)\Big)$$

Now since $(123\cdots m)$ together with $(12)$ generate $S_m$, we will find that in this new subgroup we can individually permute the first $n_1$ elements in any way we want, the same holds for the $n_2$ elements after that etc... But we can not exchange any elements between two "blocks" of $n_i$ elements. Now convince yourself that this is isomorphic to $S_{n_1}\times\cdots\times S_{n_k}$.